# Mobile First Responsive Image Technique

Tags: css, responsive-design

What is the current standard way to handle responsive images in a mobile first approach?

That is: is there an accepted method in use today that allows small resolution images to be served to mobile/small screen width devices, while larger resolution images be served to tablet/desktop etc.?

Comment: Media queries [link](http://www.google.co.uk/#q=css3+media+queries&hl=en&safe=off&biw=1917&bih=1102&fp=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&cad=b)

Comment: Not media queries, with media queries you cannot direct server to serve different resolution images afaik

Comment: No, you REQUEST a different size image FROM the server by using media queries to load relevant CSS for the screen size.

Comment: Not css background images but actual images: <img>

Answer (score 1):

Omit `width` and `height` on the `<img />` tag, if it's parent element is responsive it'll scale.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, as sanusart wrote you.

For example, if you use Twitter Bootstrap extension (recognized by many as the best or one of the best responsive design-oriented frameworks) and set it to use [responsive design](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) (not set, by default), then all you have to do, is to put your image inside responsive container, for example `well`:

```
<div class="well">
    <img src="img/logo.png" class="img-polaroid" />
</div>
```

And your image will adapt its dimensions according to screen resolution.

If you would like to separate it with left and right margin,
you can use [fluid layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#fluidGridSystem), for example like that:

```
<div class="well">  
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span2"></div>
        <div class="span8"><img src="img/sunflower.jpg" /></div>
        <div class="span2"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But we aware, that on a wide screens (like phones in portrait mode) your left and right "separators" [will be stacked top and bottom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14891349/1469208), which may produce unwanted side effects.