# Making a Website Responsive with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have been working on a website for some time and have most of the site built on twitter bootstrap.  The site looks great for browsers bigger than 900px but smaller than that the columns start to overlap and look pretty bad.  I am wondering if there is any advice for what to do to prevent this overlap such as CSS options and some HTML work.  It is happening in a lot of areas but here is an example.  I know this one is having some trouble because I have set the width to wider than the column but that is the way it looks best.

```
<div class="row">
        <span class="span8">
            <h2>Some Title!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>stuff here</li> 
                <li>I have some stuff here</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="alert alert-warning center-it">
                You can share if you <a href="/login">login or register</a>
            </div>  
            <br>
        </span>

        <form method="get">
            <span class="span4">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search for the location" style="width:300px; height: 30px;" class="pull-right" name="location" size="55" /><br><br><br>
                <span class="pull-right">
                    <h4>Within: 
                        <select name="radius">
                            <option value="25">25 miles</option>
                            <option value="50">50 miles</option>
                            <option value="100" selected>100 miles</option>
                            <option value="200">200 miles</option>
                            <option value="400">400 miles</option>
                        </select>
                    </h4>
                    </span>
                    <br><br><br>
                    <input class="btn pull-right" type="submit">
            </span>
        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: Did you include the responsive css and added the meta viewport tag?

Comment: yes I have, see comment on Rishi's answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into the same issue. As you can read in a comment to [Bootstrap's Live Grid Example](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem): "*Below 767px viewports, the columns become fluid and stack vertically*". I'm afraid that there's not much that you (we) can do about this.

For the first time, I was also badly impressed. If I'm buidling a grid system with left (and/or) right sidebars, I want left and right sidebars to be left and right, not stacked to the top and bottom of the main column. 
But, after re-thinking the idea, I agreed for the compromise, that this is just how grid / fluid grid system works in Bootstrap. Many things that Bootstrap is best or one of the best frameworks for responsive design, so I think, we have to accept like it works and not try to make wheel more quadrat, right?

The only option I see for you is to resign from column-based layout. Or accept that when using it, your columns will overlap and stack vertically on small viewports.

If you're designing a mobile app, there is some kind of solution, that you may force your app to work in landscape mode only, and have sidebars there, where you designed them. But, when you're dealing with mobile website, I don't see much more you can do.

Comment: It's not a compromise, it's by design. On mobile phones a grid with left and right columns is not very convenient, therefore bootstrap stacks them on top of each other. It makes a lot of sense to me.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, _now_ it also makes sense to me! :]

Answer (score 0):

download *bootstrap.css* and *bootstrap-responsive.css*, put them under *bootstrap* directory and try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en"><head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <link href="bootstrap/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
     <link href="bootstrap/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
     </head>

      <body>
       <div class="row">
            <span class="span8">
                <h2>Some Title!</h2>
                <ul>
                    <li>stuff here</li> 
                    <li>I have some stuff here</li>
                </ul>
                <div class="alert alert-warning center-it">
                    You can share if you <a href="/login">login or register</a>
                </div>  
                <br>
            </span>

            <form method="get">
                <span class="span4">
                    <input type="search" placeholder="Search for the location" style="width:300px; height: 30px;" class="pull-right" name="location" size="55" /><br><br><br>
                    <span class="pull-right">
                        <h4>Within: 
                            <select name="radius">
                                <option value="25">25 miles</option>
                                <option value="50">50 miles</option>
                                <option value="100" selected>100 miles</option>
                                <option value="200">200 miles</option>
                                <option value="400">400 miles</option>
                            </select>
                        </h4>
                        </span>
                        <br><br><br>
                        <input class="btn pull-right" type="submit">
                </span>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body></html>
```

Comment: sorry I suppose I wasn't clear enough.  I have all of that in there and it is being responsive but when it resizes for a smaller browser things like text inputs, dropdowns, and other fixed width HTML elements overlap and get crammed in together.  is there any solution to this besides revising the whole layout?

Comment: afaik responsiveness is NOT fixed width HTML elements..so you need to revise your layout to make it responsive..

Answer (score 0):

If understand correctly, your input element and other divs are overlapping. If this is the issue you are encountering, set span* class values on the input elements and divs. Also the span element should not be used as a container for other HTML.

This quick pass at it looks better to me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
 <link href="resources/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 </head>

  <body>
   <div class="row">
        <div class="span8">
            <h2>Some Title!</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>stuff here</li> 
                <li>I have some stuff here</li>
            </ul>
            <div class="alert alert-warning center-it span6">
                You can share if you <a href="/login">login or register</a>
            </div>  
            <br/>
        </div>

        <form method="get">
            <div class="span4">
                <input type="search" placeholder="Search for the location" class="pull-right span4" name="location" size="55" />
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <div class="pull-right">
                    <h4>Within: 
                        <select name="radius">
                            <option value="25">25 miles</option>
                            <option value="50">50 miles</option>
                            <option value="100" selected="selected">100 miles</option>
                            <option value="200">200 miles</option>
                            <option value="400">400 miles</option>
                        </select>
                    </h4>
                </div>
                <br/><br/><br/>
                <input class="btn pull-right" type="submit"/>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

</body></html>
```