# Twitter Bootstrap with responsive design -- How to style own, non-framework elements

Tags: css, responsive-design

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap with [responsive design](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive), so on virtually any device / screeen size or density all Bootstrap elements have dimensions / font sizes fit to screen size.

But, what about my own, non-framework elements? How should I style them to follow responsive design and look the same? For example -- images. What dimension it should have and how to style it, so it would look the same on both desktop computer and mobile phone?

I had this issue with 250x250px image. On mobile website emulator on my desktop computer, it filled over half of the screen (emulator assumes medium screen size for emulated device). But when I opened this page on my Galaxy Nexus (with huge XHDPI screen densiy), 250x250px image looked just tiny.

Size are not the only problem. How to set margins / paddings of above mentioned image. so page would look quite identically on many devices. If I display that image on my desktop computer / Full HD sceen, I have nearly 2000 px of width. On Galaxy Nexus in portrait mode I'll have less than 1000 px width to use.

*I'm medium or beginner in CSS and a complete ignorant (beginner) in mobile development / resposive design, so this question may seem dumb. Sorry!*

Comment: You have a lot of questions in one question, which encourages lots of answers that only answer some of them.

Comment: Well, I must say, that I'm a little bit surprised. "_It's difficult to tell what is being asked here_". Well, for me the question is obvious and straightfoward and is placed in the topic -- _How to style own, non-framework elements in responsive design_. But OK, if you feel it is not a real question, then fine. Seems that tahdhaze09's answer (he probably assumed, this is a real question, since he had replied) and some own research must be enough for me. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: Answer to my question is as simple [as that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11442130/1469208): "_Omit `width` and `height` on the `<img />` tag, if it's parent element is responsive it'll scale._". Though -1 for me for not making enough research _before_ asking.

Comment: They could have either asked in  a comment  to clarify your question, or edited your question to make it clearer for it to be answered (I understood exactly what you were asking, since the question was a clear as day in the second paragraph). Reading the details below the questions about your issues should've been enough information for them to decipher and edit your question. It's been asked in other forums enough times for me to find it elsewhere and bookmark, before you asked. Seems a little lazy to just give a -1 and close the question without due diligence. Just my 2 cents...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the meta tag that automatically proportions everything based on the viewport:

```
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">
```

Place the above line on your `<head>` tag, and the margins, padding, and text should look good.

Images should also be proportionate, but for things like large background images on the `body` or large `div`s, you would need to alter the bootstrap-responsive.css file to bring in the 'right' image. So you may want a large background image for desktops and large laptops, a medium size image in a different spot for tablets, and a seamless pattern image for smartphones. Just look for the @media portions of the file and add/edit the css.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That really is a, what I've been asking for and it seems to be a good starting point for my further reasearch. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome! Good luck with your bootstrap layout.